# hibernate error: cannot insert into a table

Tags: hibernate

what does this exception mean?

```
ERROR : org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter:78 : logExceptions() : There is no 'root'@'%' registered
...
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: There is no 'root'@'%' registered
```

I get this exception when trying to insert into a table of mysql database

Comment: Looks like the credentials you are using to connect to the db are wrong.

Comment: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,237843,238950#msg-238950

Comment: thanks a lot, I resolved it following forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,237843,238950#msg-238950